# Moving the mouse cursor doesn't work as expected on X11

Tags: c, linux, x11

I'm trying to move the mouse pointer while the left button is down (Button1).
But it doesn't work. For example, if I launch GIMP, I see a dot (cursor down), then the cursor moves but without drawing. I was expecting to see a drawn line (move while holding left button down).

```
Display * display = XOpenDisplay(0);
XEvent event;
memset (&event, 0, sizeof (event));
event.xbutton.button = Button1;
event.xbutton.same_screen = True;
event.xbutton.subwindow = DefaultRootWindow (display);
while (event.xbutton.subwindow)
{
event.xbutton.window = event.xbutton.subwindow;
XQueryPointer (display, event.xbutton.window,
           &event.xbutton.root, &event.xbutton.subwindow,
           &event.xbutton.x_root, &event.xbutton.y_root,
           &event.xbutton.x, &event.xbutton.y,
           &event.xbutton.state);
}
// Press
event.type = ButtonPress;
if (XSendEvent (display, PointerWindow, True, 0xFFF, &event) == 0)
fprintf (stderr, "Error to send the event!\n");

XFlush (display);

// Move
XWarpPointer(display, None, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 50, 50);

XFlush (display);

// Release
event.type = ButtonRelease;
event.xbutton.state = 0x100;

if (XSendEvent (display, PointerWindow, True, 0xFFF, &event) == 0)
fprintf (stderr, "Error to send the event!\n");

XFlush (display);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Nicolas.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [XTest extension library](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/Xext/xtestlib.pdf) to fake user input events.

Comment: Thanks, I'am tryingg it, it seems to work better. Is this library always provided with X?

Comment: It's an extension, so in principle a server need not support it. That said, it is very old. I don't know if any real server today lacks it.